# Semicircle not touching axis, labeling origin in the form (0,0) -- pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've plotted an upper semicircle of radius 1 centered at the origin, but the semicircle does not touch the x-axis at $x = 1$; instead, it leaves a gap.  But it does seem to touch at $x = -1$.

I also want to remove all x-axis ticks marks and numbers, and instead plot a point at the origin and label it $(0,0)$ below it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = none,
    axis line style = {-},
    height = {8.5cm},
    width = {12cm},
    xtick={0},
]
\addplot [
    domain=-1:1, 
    samples=800, 
    color=black,
]
{(1-x^2)^0.5};

\addplot [only marks,samples at={0}] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I adjusted the height and width to get it to proportion correctly thinking that that might get the semicircle to touch the axis, but it doesn't work.

How can I get the semicircle to touch the x-axis as it should at 1 and -1?  How do I remove the 0 and vertical tick mark on the x-axis and instead plot a point there with the label (0,0) underneath it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[cyan] (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
        \draw[cyan] (-1,0)--(1,0);
        \draw[cyan] (0,0.1)--(0,0);
        \node[below] at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: To draw the centre at (0,0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[cyan] (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
        \draw[cyan] (-1,0)--(1,0);
        %\draw[cyan] (0,0.1)--(0,0);
        \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(.5pt);
        \node[below] at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT1: If you want an inscribed rectangle in the semicircle you can code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[cyan] (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
        \draw[cyan] (-1,0)--(1,0);
        %\draw[cyan] (0,0.1)--(0,0);
        \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(.5pt);
        \draw[magenta,line width=2pt] (-.3,0) rectangle (.3,{sqrt(1-.3^2)});
        \node[below] at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with this output:

[image]

Comment: I see how to remove the vertical line, but how to add a point at (0,0)?  Also, can I use ```addplot``` to add an inscribed rectangle in this figure?

Comment: To add a point at the origin I used the ```[%
  decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.50 with {\coordinate (A); \fill[red] circle [radius=2pt];},
    }]]``` as an option along with the ```decorations.markings``` library.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood what is your problem, than adding `enlargelimits=false` to `axis` option solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   % it load tikz too
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}  % better than use {compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width = {12cm},
    axis equal,             % <--- new
    enlargelimits=false,    % <--- new   
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = none,
    axis line style = {-},
    xtick={0},
]
\addplot [
    domain=-1:1,
    samples=101,
]
{(1-x^2)^0.5};

%\addplot [only marks,samples at={0}] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Apparently your problem is not what you asking for in question but simple how to draw semicircle on any way. This means, that your question is misleading ... Anyway, with `tikz` the image code can be very short and simple:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% rectangle
\draw[red, very thick] (-1.2,0) rectangle (1.2,{sqrt(4^2-1.2^2)});
% arc+dot
\draw       (0,0) -- (4,0) arc (0:180:4) -- cycle;
\filldraw   (0,0) circle(2pt) node[below] {$(0,0)$};
        \;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where `arc (0:180:4)` is abbreviation for `arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=4cm]`. For details see
Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, first tutorial.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this for some reason.  I've added both ```axis equal``` and ```enlargelimits=false```.  Are those the only changes?

Comment: @UngarLinski, yes, that is all. BTW, at my `pgfplots` version` the `compat = newest` is equal to `compat = 1.18` (I now accordingly correct code, see edited answer). Which version of `pgfplots` you have installed? My  MWE works with all version after 1.11.

Comment: @UngarLinski, apparently you not looking for what you asked in question. With pure Ti*k*Z picture code is simpler, of course. See edited answer.